# R_loading R data files in a loop and assigning a same variable name

Tags: r, for-loop, assign

Hi I have several `RData` files with the same file name and object name. For example one of the file names is `int.5.RData` where the dataframe `int.5` is saved. I have several similar files with names `int.5.RData`, `int.10.RData`, and so on. Now I have to load them  and assign a same variable name (say `new.int`) to the data frames( `int.5`, `int.10`, etc) in a `for loop`. I can load them by using `load(paste0("int",i,".RData"))` in the `for loop` where `i` is `c(5,10,...)`, But I am stuck with the next step where I have to assign the data frames (`int.5`, `int.10`,etc) the same name, `int.new` in the same loop as I can't use `paste`command for that operation. Can anybody help me here?

Comment: Better to read the data into a list. See [gregor's answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44948104/r-loading-r-data-files-in-a-loop-and-assigning-a-same-variable-name).

Comment: can you post what you've done already in full in addition to describing it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<s>Look at `assign`..</s>

### Edit:

In that case look at `get` function:

```
> a <- 5
> get("a")
[1] 5
```

Comment: I had a look at `assign` already. But in my case `nam` is always same (i.e. `new.int`) and the objects this name be assigned to is different everytime (i.e. `int.5`, `int.10`, etc)